# Name of B western movie that starts with horse race

Tags: identify-this-movie, western

Looking for name of B western movie in color from "50-60 seen on TV. It starts out with a horse race in a town out west. A stranger rides in at the last minute, hands a couple of law books to an old character actor, enters the race, and wins by lassoing a flag stuck in the ground to, barely, beat a pretty cowgirl. A saloon in the background at the start was the "Turlock Palace" owned by the bad guy, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Michael Curtiz's B Western [The Boy from Oklahoma](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046804/combined) from 1954. From the [TCM synopsis](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/69510/The-Boy-from-Oklahoma/full-synopsis.html):

> On his way to an apprenticeship in Lincoln, **Tom Brewster, a correspondence school law student from Oklahoma**, rides into the corrupt town of Blue Rock to mail his examination papers. The post office is closed because it is Election Day, but alcohol flows freely in **the saloon owned by incumbent mayor Barney Turlock**, who buys his victory. [...] During the festivities, **Tom ties in a horse race with tomboy Katie Brannigan**, then loses to her in a shooting match, as he never carries arms.

Here's a clip from the movie:

Comment: Thank you Napoleon; independently,found out last night crosschecking two remembered bit players, Sheb Wooley and Slim Pickens. Thanks again, because I might not have.